# Maintaining a generator function instance across sub-classes

Tags: typescript

I have a ROOT NODE class that, when instantiated, should always have ID 0.

Each child object from this ROOT NODE should have an integer ID sequentially for their creation [1 for first child, 2 for second, etc]. Child nodes are a subclass of ROOT NODE.

My original implementation was to have a generator function that ROOT NODE refers to for its ID, and then the CHILD NODES refer to ROOT NODE to get their ID. This is shown below and functions as intended:

```ts
const skillIdGenerator = (function* () {
  let id = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield id;
    id++;
  }
})();

class RootNode {
  private id: number;
  private children: Map<number, Skill>;

  constructor() {
    this.id = skillIdGenerator.next().value;
    this.children = new Map();
  }

  getId(): number {
    return this.id;
  }
}

class Node extends RootNode {
  private parents: Map<number, RootSkill | Skill>;

  constructor(parentSkills: (RootSkill | Skill)[], name: string) {
    super();
    this.parents = new Map(parentSkills.map((p) => [p.getId(), p]));
  }
}
```

However, this does not work if there are multiple trees and therefore multiple ROOT NODEs.

**What is the best way to maintain a generator for all children of each ROOT NODE, and instantiate a new generator for each new ROOT NODE?**

---

I have tried moving the `skillIdGenerator` into the ROOT NODE class in two different ways: as a function that returns the next ID, and as a generator that can be iterated; both failed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this hierarchy is wrong. If `RootNode` is special, then `Node` shouldn't really inherit from it. However, if any node is a root node (that is normally correct as any sub-tree is still a tree) then the difference seems forced. I'm not sure the best way to fix the hierarchy here. Depends on how you intend to use them. A simple solution might be to have a `Tree` class that creates and manages nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try and find another way to structure my code. I'm still hopeful for a solution here though.

Comment: @VLAZ I think your solution is best - if you post it as an answer in a way that relates to the generator I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: I'm working on another solution right now. Give me a while to refine it and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proposed hierarchy is incorrect for building a tree. There is essentially no difference between a root node and any other node. In a tree, every sub-tree is still logically a tree. It does not make much sense to differentiate `RootNode` and `Node`. Moreover, you want your nodes intrinsically linked in your case. I suggest replacing the two classes with a single one:

```
const skillIdGenerator = function* () {
  let id = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield id;
    id++;
  }
};

class TreeNode {
  private id: number;
  private children: Map<number, TreeNode> = new Map();

  private constructor(private idGenerator: Generator<number>, private parents: Map<number, TreeNode> | null = null) {
    this.parents  = parents;
    this.id = this.idGenerator.next().value;
  }

  getId(): number {
    return this.id;
  }

  getChildren(): ReadonlyMap<number, TreeNode> {
    return this.children;
  }

  getParents(): ReadonlyMap<number, TreeNode> {
    return this.parents ?? new Map();
  }

  get isRoot() {
    return this.parents === null;
  }

  static createRootNode() {
    const node = new TreeNode(skillIdGenerator());
    return node;
  }

  createNode() {
    const newParents = new Map(this.parents ?? [])
      .set(this.getId(), this);

    const node =  new TreeNode(this.idGenerator, newParents);
    this.children.set(node.getId(), node);
    return node;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link with demo usage](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=62&ssc=1&pln=74&pc=24#code/MYewdgzgLgBBDWBLANsgkgEwOIFMw4CcBDKEAmAXhgDMBXMYKRcAKhgAoBKGAbwCgYMZDliIMlGAAYA3AJgB3ABYocHKAVo5u-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-P3Vz11gOKEoAGQ8ryqHKgqHOijKysQeKoEFFqEu8jr6qKxq+DqqrPJS4r0rcgBHTRNAkQcfNjYdnBQlCIEUKiLDAciCBSUNwBgIg0hAWhYFI+i-D4JQVHYCacE0X5hFo74mzyUq8gZI4JCum7lsQTyuAAQmkGBFogWgwgiHAPG8ABlBRDjAGi6MI0jfCA3bkHkIg9E8IkQHh5k8IyXamUQIYUjkOQPqMsJaGW9hfjp4BXqBV9uV5flOBxIg8XBrhryeiy7y1MBME8KgAEECGIPRfmoHyUnYBmJaZuceU1NnfngHBMZ5mlfgAKxxsB2AAInqI3ebcogGHBxZhYkcXJel2X5cZo1mf1GCIGxDWtZLHX9Zo42CLaM25GTQzbpAIl2AAA0-BRicUGA0EwmAABIeAVo43YXOxmMERR3AODtB3Ty3gGtshhbsYc5ALzwBaKGAS4z1m8Cr4do7HBwgA)

The important difference is that the construction has been restricted to factory methods only:

- `createRootNode()` - static method so if you call it, you always start a new tree. A new generator is started as part of the instantiation and passed to the constructor. The ID is derived from there.
- `createNode()` - instance method, so it is only valid within an existing tree. The current existing generator is passed within the constructor and the ID is taken as the next item from it.

That makes all nodes share a reference to the same generator object. While slightly unnecessary, it is for slight convenience for creation of new nodes.

Demo usage for generating:

```
    0
  / | \
 1  2  3
 |    / \
 4   5   6
     |
     7
```

```
const root = TreeNode.createRootNode();

const left  = root.createNode();
const mid   = root.createNode();
const right = root.createNode();

const leftMid = left.createNode();

const rightLeft  = right.createNode();
const rightRight = right.createNode();

rightLeft.createNode();
```

Comment: Can you please explain why `isRoot` is prefaced by `get` but none of the other getters are?

Comment: @LaytonGB meh, no good reason. I was going to use it for the traversal at the bottom of the demo but then went in a different direction. It's left over code, basically. And whether you implement getters as `get foo() {}` or `getFoo()` is a bit of a preference. The main consideration is what sort of API you want to present to consumers. But since this is demo code, it doesn't matter as much. It can be changed as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code so that `skillIdGenerator` is not an IIFE which creates a Generator object. Without invoking it, you are simply defining a generator function. In that way, you can instantiate a new Generator object per `RootNode` instance:

```ts
const skillIdGenerator = function* () {
  let id = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield id;
    id++;
  }
};

class RootNode {
  private id: number;
  private children: Map<number, Skill>;
  private skillId = skillIdGenerator();

  constructor() {
    this.id = skillId.next().value;
    this.children = new Map();
  }

  getId(): number {
    return this.id;
  }
}
```

Comment: `class Node extends RootNode` calls `super()` in the constructor, so it will also start a new generator.

Comment: @VLAZ But isn't this what OP wants? Each RootNode now has its own Generator object.

Comment: Each `RootNode`, not each `Node`. OP seems to want to build up a tree starting at `RootNode` and appending `Node`s to it but then `Node`s for a tree should have a single source of IDs. If each `Node` also instantiates a generator then `new Node()` will set `id = 0` for each one because each starts a fresh generator and takes the first value.